# request.format in rescue_from block

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails controller with a `rescue_from` block in which I call `render`.

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  rescue_from Some::Error, :some_error

  private

  def some_error error
    @error = error
    render 'error'
  end
end
```

The strange thing is that even if I have an `error.js.erb` view, rails will always use `error.html.erb`, even if the request is a `JS`:

```
Started GET /some/1
Processing by SomeController#show as JS
...
Rendered some/error.html.erb
```

Not how in the shortened log above it says it's rendering as JS, but it still uses the HTML file. The `.js.erb` is at the right location, and rendering JS views when there's no `rescue_from` involved works just fine.

What's going on here?

**Update 1**: *I have created a [test repository](https://github.com/amiuhle/request.format-in-rescue_from-block) to demonstrate the problem*

**Update 2** *I've found a solution (see below). Can anyone come up with a more generic solution like the ones below, or can you tell my why this would be impossible or a really bad idea? The bounty is still open.*

- Would it make sense to create a pull request to set `self.formats` in `ActionController::Rescue.process_action` *or*
- Get really crazy and try to resume the stack one level deeper than where the error was raised

Comment: Have you tried `render 'error', format: request.format`?

Comment: I have updated the question with a link to a test repository. If I add `formats: request.format` it will throw an error saying it can't find a template to render.

Answer (score 6):

**Solution**

I did some debugging and digging around in the rails sources and found a solution myself:

```
def error
  @error = error
  self.formats = request.formats.map(&:ref).compact
  render 'error'
end
```

**Explanation**

Calling the `rescue_from` block happens in [`ActionController::Rescue.process_action`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f62fb985b6a7b90872148f0786219c9cc94c9356/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb#L28). If there is an error, the block will be called. If there is no error, eventually [`ActionController::Rendering.process_action`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f62fb985b6a7b90872148f0786219c9cc94c9356/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb#L8) will get called which just sets `self.formats`:

```
def process_action(*) #:nodoc:
  self.formats = request.formats.map(&:ref).compact
  super
end
```

Here is a full stacktrace between `ActionController::Rescue.process_action` and the actual controller action.

```
#0  TestController.index at /tmp/rescue_from/app/controllers/test_controller.rb:11
#1  ActionController::ImplicitRender.send_action(method#String, *args#Array) at /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4
#2  AbstractController::Base.process_action(action#NilClass, *args#Array) at /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198
#3  ActionController::Rendering.process_action(action, *args) at /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10
#4  block in AbstractController::Callbacks.process_action(action#NilClass, *args#Array) at /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20
ͱ-- #5  Proc.call(*args) at /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:115
#6  ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Filters::End.call(env#ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Filters::Environment) at /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:115
#7  block (2 levels) in ActiveSupport::Callbacks::CallbackChain.compile at /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:553
ͱ-- #8  Proc.call(*args) at /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:503
#9  ActiveSupport::Callbacks::CallbackSequence.call(*args#Array) at /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:503
#10 ActiveSupport::Callbacks.run_callbacks(kind#Symbol, &block#Proc) at /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88
#11 AbstractController::Callbacks.process_action(action#NilClass, *args#Array) at /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19
#12 ActionController::Rescue.process_action(action#NilClass, *args#Array) at /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29
```

Here is a full stacktrace when there is an error (thrown in a `before_action`):

```
--> #0  TestController.standard_error(error#RuntimeError) at /Users/timou/tmp/rescue_from/app/controllers/test_controller.rb:20
ͱ-- #1  Method.call(*args) at /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/rescuable.rb:80
#2  ActiveSupport::Rescuable.rescue_with_handler(exception#RuntimeError) at /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/rescuable.rb:80
#3  ActionController::Rescue.rescue_with_handler(exception#RuntimeError) at /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:15
#4  rescue in ActionController::Rescue.process_action(action#NilClass, *args#Array) at /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:32
#5  ActionController::Rescue.process_action(action#NilClass, *args#Array) at /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29
```

So my problem was actually that the error is raised in a `before_action`, which is handled by `AbstractController::Callbacks.process_action` and happens before `ActionController::Rendering.process_action` can set `self.formats`.

If the error is raised in the action itself, `self.formats` would already be set and the correct view would be rendered without settings `self.formats` in the `rescue_from` block.